# pandas groupby dates and years and sum up amounts

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe like this:

```
d = {'dollar_amount': ['200.25', '350.00', '120.00', '400.50', '1231.25', '700.00', '350.00', '200.25', '2340.00'], 'date': ['22-01-2010','22-01-2010','23-01-2010','15-02-2010','27-02-2010','07-03-2010','14-01-2011','09-10-2011','28-07-2012']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.4f}'.format
df['dollar_amount'] = df['dollar_amount'].astype(float)
df

    date        dollar_amount
0   22-01-2010  200.25
1   22-01-2010  350.00
2   23-01-2010  120.00
3   15-02-2010  400.50
4   27-02-2010  1231.25
5   07-03-2010  700.00
6   14-01-2011  350.00
7   09-10-2011  200.25
8   11-11-2011  2340.00
9   12-12-2011  144.50
10  12-09-2012  760.00
11  22-10-2012  255.00
12  28-07-2012  650.00
```

I want to sum amounts for each day in each year.
So I am dividing the years like this:

```
date1 = df[(df['date'] >= '2010-01-01') & (df['date'] < '2011-01-01')]
date2 = df[(df['date'] >= '2011-01-01') & (df['date'] < '2012-01-01')]
date3 = df[(df['date'] >= '2012-01-01') & (df['date'] < '2013-01-01')]
```

So now I have 3 dataframes with dates from the year 2010 in `date1` dataframe,
dates from the year 2011 in `date2` and dates from 2012 in `date3`.

Lets look at `date1`:

```
print type(date1)
date1

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

    date        dollar_amount
0   2010-01-22  200.2500
1   2010-01-22  350.0000
2   2010-01-23  120.0000
3   2010-02-15  400.5000
4   2010-02-27  1,231.2500
5   2010-03-07  700.0000
```

Next I am summing up the amounts date wise, so I am grouping on date using this:

```
date1 = date1.groupby('date', as_index=False).sum()
date1 = date1[['date','dollar_amount']].sort_values(by=['date'], 
ascending=True)

date2 = date2.groupby('date', as_index=False).sum()
date2 = date2[['date','dollar_amount']].sort_values(by=['date'], 
ascending=True)

date3 = date3.groupby('date', as_index=False).sum()
date3 = date3[['date','dollar_amount']].sort_values(by=['date'], 
ascending=True)
```

Let's look at the dateframe `date1` now:

```
date1

date        dollar_amount
0   2010-01-22  550.2500
1   2010-01-23  120.0000
2   2010-02-15  400.5000
3   2010-02-27  1,231.2500
4   2010-03-07  700.0000
```

This is just sorting them in ascending date wise order:

```
date1 = date1[['date','dollar_amount']].sort_values(by=['date'], 
ascending=True)
```

Now I have got the date wise sum of dollarAmounts for each year in different dataframes. Then I am plotting traces for each year. Its working fine and fulfilling the task. But this code is very redundant and I am copying the same code and if I have say data from year 2000 to 2017 then I will have to copy and paste the same piece of code 18 times. I think its not very effective way of doing this.

I am sure there must be a better way of doing this but I cant figure out how. Kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can create `MultiIndex` by `year`s to output:

```
df1 = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['dollar_amount'].sum()
df1 = df1.set_index(df['date'].rename('year').dt.year, append=True).swaplevel(0,1)
print (df1)
             date  dollar_amount
year                            
2010 0 2010-01-22       550.2500
     1 2010-01-23       120.0000
     2 2010-02-15       400.5000
     3 2010-02-27     1,231.2500
     4 2010-03-07       700.0000
2011 5 2011-01-14       350.0000
     6 2011-10-09       200.2500
2012 7 2012-07-28     2,340.0000

print (df1.loc[2010])
        date  dollar_amount
0 2010-01-22       550.2500
1 2010-01-23       120.0000
2 2010-02-15       400.5000
3 2010-02-27     1,231.2500
4 2010-03-07       700.0000

print (df1.loc[2011])
        date  dollar_amount
5 2011-01-14       350.0000
6 2011-10-09       200.2500

print (df1.loc[2012])
        date  dollar_amount
7 2012-07-28     2,340.0000
```

If want create `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['date'].dt.year)))
print (d)

print (d[2010])
        date  dollar_amount
0 2010-01-22       550.2500
1 2010-01-23       120.0000
2 2010-02-15       400.5000
3 2010-02-27     1,231.2500
4 2010-03-07       700.0000

print (d[2011])
        date  dollar_amount
5 2011-01-14       350.0000
6 2011-10-09       200.2500

print (d[2012])
        date  dollar_amount
7 2012-07-28     2,340.0000
```

Comment: But Its summing up for years. I want to sum up against dates and then divide the resulting dataframe for years

Comment: Is necessary create dataframes for each year?

Comment: I think I am not explaining my question correctly. Let me make some edits.

Comment: OK, so expected output are 3 DataFrames? Or plot?

Comment: There is no expected outcome. The code is working fine. But I want to reduce the redundancy of the code. I am repeating the same line of codes for by creating 3 dataframes. What I am looking for is a way to to do the same task effectively. Hope I am explaining correctly.

Comment: I create 2 possible general solutions, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'dollar_amount': ['200.25', '350.00', '120.00', '400.50', '1231.25', '700.00', '350.00', '200.25', '2340.00'], 'date': ['22-01-2010','22-01-2010','23-01-2010','15-02-2010','27-02-2010','07-03-2010','14-01-2011','09-10-2011','28-07-2012']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# convert dates to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# convert amounts to floats
df['dollar_amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['dollar_amount'])
# set date as the index and drop the date column
df.index = df.date
df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
# resample the dataframe every 1 day (D) and sum ovr each day
df = df.resample('D').sum()
# eliminate the rows where the sum is 0 (i.e. rows which were not in the original dataframe)
df = df[~(df['dollar_amount'].isnull())]
```

Output:

```
            dollar_amount
date                     
2010-01-22         550.25
2010-01-23         120.00
2010-02-15         400.50
2010-02-27        1231.25
2010-07-03         700.00
2011-01-14         350.00
2011-09-10         200.25
2012-07-28        2340.00
```